# How do you write a task to run tests in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake-task, rake-test

I would like to write rake tasks to customize tests. For example, to run unit tests, I created a file with the following code and saved it as lib/tasks/test.rake:

```
task :do_unit_tests do
  cd #{Rails.root} 
  rake test:units
end
```

Running `rake do_unit_tests` throws an error: `can't convert Hash into String`.

Working in Rails 3.0.7 and using built-in unit test framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to `cd`. You can simply...

```
task :do_unit_tests do
  Rake::Task['test:units'].invoke
end
```

But if you really want to `cd`, that's how you call shell instructions:

```
task :do_unit_tests do
  sh "cd #{Rails.root}"
  Rake::Task['test:units'].invoke
end
```

Well, in fact there is a shorter version. The `cd` instruction have a special alias as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203114/chris) mentioned in the other answer, so you can just...

```
task :do_unit_tests do
  cd Rails.root
  Rake::Task['test:units'].invoke
end
```

If you want to go further, I recommend [Jason Seifer's Rake Tutorial](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial) and [Martin Fowler's Using the Rake Build Language](http://martinfowler.com/articles/rake.html) articles. Both are great.

Comment: I suppose you may highlight the sentence: "There is no need to cd". I would say it may also be a little dangerous when not called with a block, because it would (if it wasn't already the same) change the current directory for all other actions. And also your first suggestion of using `sh "cd ..."` would not work, because the path would be changed only in a new process of shell, which ends as soon as the directory is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to interpolate a value that's not in a string, and you're also treating `rake test:units` like it were a method call with arguments, which it's not.

Change the `cd` line so you're calling the method with the value of `Rails.root`, and change the second line to be a shell instruction.

```
task :do_unit_tests do
  cd Rails.root
  `rake test:units`
end
```

Comment: This throws an error: `undefined local variable or method 'units' for main:Object`.

Comment: I only read and fixed the first line. I've now updated the second line to be a system command, so there's no errors in the code. Still, there's more appropriate ways to do this, as [jmonteiro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/131947/jmonteiro) has described.

Comment: This threw an error as well. Adding `--trace` reveals `rake aborted!Command failed with status (1): [/home/baller/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/b...]
/home/baller/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995:in 'block in sh'`